# How do i configure HBase in Azure HDInsight's Spark Cluster?

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

I have created HDInsight's Spark cluster in Azure. Now i wanted to store the processed data into HBASE and I dont want to create separate HBASE HDInsight Cluster and connect to the Spark cluster with VNET.

This is because we have restriction of 60 Cores per region(Eg. East US 2). I have and wanted to use all 60 cores for my Spark Cluster. So thought of installing HBASE inside HDInsight's spark Cluster.

It Seems there is an HBASE instance running already when I create in HDInsight Spark Cluster. But this doesn't show in Azure's Cluster Dashboard(Ambari) or any of its configuration.

And i'm not sure it is working properly. When I did a "hbase shell" I got the error as shown below.

[image: HBASE Error on "hbase shell" in Spark HDInsight Cluster]

So how can I do a proper hbase installation and configure it in my Spark HDInsight cluster? and is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported scenario in HDInsight. We have HBase as separate supported cluster type. You can increase the quota by raising a support ticket from Azure Management Portal.